# Storing CognitoUser in cache make him lose some properties

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, amazon-cognito, session-storage

I'm currently using AWS Cognito in my application.

When a user first connects whit his account, Cognito returns NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED as a challenge, which is fine.

I want to redirect to a page where the user can set his new password, so I put the response from Auth.signIn in storage (I tried local storage, session storage and Cache from AWS Amplify) but when I get it back on the other page, it lose some properties and Auth.completeNewPassword returns the error : 'user.completeNewPasswordChallenge is not a function'

Login.js :

```
try {
  var authPromise = Auth.signIn(this.state.email, this.state.password);
  authPromise.then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
    if (result.challengeName === 'NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED') {
      Cache.setItem("CognitoUser", result);
      this.props.history.push("/login/newPassword");
    }
    else {
      this.props.userHasAuthenticated(true);
      this.props.history.push("/");
    }
  });
} catch (e) {
  alert(e.message);
  this.setState({ isLoading: false });
}
```

NewPassword.js :

```
    try {
        var user = Cache.getItem("CognitoUser");
        if (user) {
            await Auth.completeNewPassword(user, this.state.newPassword);
            this.props.history.push("/");
            Cache.removeItem("CognitoUser");
        }
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e.message);
        this.setState({ isChanging: false });
    }
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's javascript so when you write to your localcache and serializes your `result` into the `"CognitoUser"` key , it's stored as a a string, which afterwards deserialized will be a plain old `Object` unaware of the original type before serialization.

Original cause is maybe that your "result" type may expose functions which are not serializable (if not a getter, or if a getter with arguments).
I suggest you to call and store all the data you want into separate keys and re-read them later.

```js
Cache.setItem("CognitoUser", result);
Cache.setItem("CognitoUser-value-1", result.myFunction1("myArg1"));
Cache.setItem("CognitoUser-value-2", result.myFunction2("myArg2"));

// ..

var user = Cache.getItem("CognitoUser");
var myVal1 = Cache.getItem("CognitoUser-value-1");
var myVal2 = Cache.getItem("CognitoUser-value-2");
```

You can also keep one single key `"CognitoUser"` in your localStorage if you make all said functions serializable. For instance, extend the type of your `result` adding prototypes getter functions (no arguments), each calling and returning respective `myFunctionX("myArgX")` functions, so that they'll appear in the *JSON.stringify* process.

Answer (score -1):

My work around,

So this problem troubled me for some time. Amplify Cache didn't seem to work and caching username and password is a bad idea, however my work around was just include the username and password in the Require-New-Password form, so I have 4 inputs instead of just newPassword & confirmPassword which now is username, oldPassword, newPassword, and confirmPassword.

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/1715#issuecomment-642733574